# ActionCable broadcast_to not reaching user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have a basic setup with rails + devise + actioncable.

I basically want to send notifications directly and privately to currently signed-in user. My code looks like follows:

#### connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### notifications_channel.rb

```
class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from current_user
  end
end
```

And it all works just fine. Client get's connected and i can see in the logs he is correctly logged in. Also, i can see a following input in the rails console:

```
[ActionCable] [admin@example.com] Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vcHJpc21vL1VzZXIvMQ)
[ActionCable] [admin@example.com] NotificationsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
[ActionCable] [admin@example.com] NotificationsChannel is streaming from #<User:0x00007f87f4180b68>
```

However, when trying to send a notification to this user using a code below, it seems the event is not reaching the user (no errors present!):

```
2.5.1 :010 > NotificationsChannel.broadcast_to(User.first, test: 'foo')
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to notifications:Z2lkOi8vcHJpc21vL1VzZXIvMQ: {:test=>"pass"}
 => nil
```

And my javascript consumer logs nothing:

```
let cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(`ws://mydomain.com/cable`)

let actions = {
  received(payload) {
    console.log(payload) // <== this line logs nothing!
  }
}

cable.subscriptions.create('NotificationsChannel', actions)
```

Have i done anything wrong in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely because you are using `stream_from` instead of `stream_for`. When referencing an object (model) rather than a string in your channel, you should use `stream_for`. Try and do this in `notifications_channel.rb`:

```
class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_for current_user
  end
end
```

Here is a reference to the documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Streams.html#method-i-stream_for

Comment: oh, right. I missed that. Anyway, it's still not working but there is a tiny progress - rails logs shows that client is listening `from notifications:Z2lkOi8vcHJpc21vL1VzZXIvMQ` which maches the output of `broadcast_to`: `Broadcasting to notifications:Z2lkOi8vcHJpc21vL1VzZXIvMQ`

however, the message is still not delivered somehow

Comment: oh, ok - i forgot to set the development adapter to redis which is crucial for sending console -> server messages.

Comment: did that fix it?

Comment: yeah, but your change was also crucial. Thanks!

Comment: 2 hours debugging to find out it was stream_for instead of stream_from, they look so similar in the code, oh my god, thanks!